# Does anyone know how I can create a CollectionInitializer for a StackLayout?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I am doing this:

```
CustomFrame = new StackLayout()
{
    Children =
    {
        new EmptyGrid(),
        new ContentLine(),
    }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is to have a special kind of StackLayout so I can do this this:

```
CustomFrame = new SimpleStackLayout()
{
    new EmptyGrid(),
    new ContentLine(),
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) states:

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element initializers when you initialize a collection type that implements IEnumerable and has Add with the appropriate signature as an instance method or an extension method.

We should therefore be able to create a derived class that implements this `Add` method and the required `IEnumerable`:

```
public class SimpleStackLayout : StackLayout, IEnumerable<View>
{
    public void Add(View view)
    {
        this.Children.Add(view);
    }

    public IEnumerator<View> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Children.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Children.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

You can now initialize it as you desire:

```cs
CustomFrame = new SimpleStackLayout()
{
    new EmptyGrid(),
    new ContentLine(),
}
```